# Need help debugging CLLocation code to find distance between two points

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cllocation

I am trying to deploy the following code in my View-Based app, but I am getting the following errors when I try to run it:

GPSViewController.h

```
CLLocationManager *lm;
CLLocation *firstLocation;
CLLocation *secondLocation;
CLLocationDistance *distance;
NSString *distanceString;
```

GPSViewController.m

```
firstLocation = [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat1 longitude:lon1] autorelease];
secondLocation = [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat2 longitude:lon2] autorelease];
distance = [secondLocation distanceFromLocation:firstLocation]; //CLLocation may not respond to distanceFromLocation

double dist = distance / 1000;  //invalid operands to binary

distanceString = [[NSString alloc] stringWithFormat: @"%f", dist];
NSLog(@"the distance between the two points is: %@", distanceString);
```

In my example code above, how do I convert the variable "distance" from a type "CLLocationDistance" to a type "double"?

I'm simply trying to calculate the distance between two points using two different CLLocation objects, and print it to the console.  lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 are doubles.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: distance should not be a pointer, just a regular CLLocationDistance (which is just a typedef'd double)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CLLocationDistance is a double, so you don't need to try to convert to double or whatsoever.

You can compute your data like this, it will work:

```
CLLocationDistance distance = [secondLocation distanceFromLocation:firstLocation];  // distance is expressed in meters

CLLocationDistance kilometers = distance / 1000.0;
NSString *distanceString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%f", kilometers];
```

Comment: romrom's answer is correct, but his code is misleading.  The distance represented by CLLocationDistance is in meters, so dividing it by 1000 will give you kilometers, not millimeters.

Comment: yup sorry for that, I'm fixing it

Comment: Thanks so much for your prompt reply.  I did as you suggested, and I get the following error message:   CLLocationDistance distance = [secondLocation distanceFromLocation:firstLocation]; //incompatible types in initialization

Comment: I initialize firstLocation and secondLocation as follows:           - (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
  didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
   fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
 
 NSString *lat = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
 latitudeTextField.text = lat;
 double lat1 = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
 
 NSString *lng = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
 longitudeTextField.text = lng;
 double lon1 = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;

Comment: Both firstLocation, and secondLocation are type CLLocation declared in GPSViewController.h as: CLLocation *firstLocation;
 CLLocation *secondLocation;

Comment: I also get the following warning:  'CLLocation' may not respond to -'distanceFromLocation' .  Thanks again for your help and patience.

Comment: CLLocationDistance is typedef'd double, declared like this by Apple: typedef double CLLocationDistance; . So that means CLLocationDistance is a primitive type, not a class. By writing CLLocationDistance *distance; you're declaring a pointer to a double. Just remove the *

Comment: distanceFromLocation: was introduced in iOS3.2 .You might be running an old version of the SDK, for which the old API was getDistanceFrom:

Comment: Thanks so much for your prompt reply, I'm still getting the error message despite having removed the *.  I also know I'm not using an older SDK because I can do iPad development with the version I'm using.  Is it possible that it has something to do with the way firstLocation, and secondLocation are declared?  Thanks again for your help.  Take care.

Comment: My sincerest apologies romrom, but you were correct.  I am using an older version of the SDK, which is why when I used the getDistanceFrom method instead, the error went away.  Thanks so much for pointing this out monsieur!

Comment: Unfortunately, I am now getting a runtime error: Unfortunately, I am now getting a runtime error:  2010-11-11 21:59:29.037 GPS[17357:207] *** -[NSPlaceholderString stringWithFormat:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b0c4c0
2010-11-11 21:59:29.222 GPS[17357:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderString stringWithFormat:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b0c4c0'
2010-11-11 21:59:29.352 GPS[17357:207] Stack: (...  Do you have any idea why I am getting this?  Thanks again for your time and patience!

Comment: I got wrong copy-pasting your code. stringWithFormat is a class method, not an instance method. So you should either call it like this: [NSString stringWithFormat:...] or like this [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:...]

Comment: Thanks very much romrom for your help.  Your solution worked!  Thank you very much for your time and patience!  All the best to you and your family.  Take care.